PSQL update with aggregate function
I'm having a problem with using a aggregate functions with UPDATE.
The p_ew is empty column from table "G5" and pow_ew is column full of recort from table "tabela".
Problem is 0 things is copied to the p_ew column.
I used this command.
UPDATE g5 SET p_ew = (SELECT avg(pow_ew) FROM tabela);
I'm trying to use other aggregate functions later to fill this table.
